# Method Log of the Node class Console is not wirting to the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I am followint that article https://nodejs.org/api/console.html how to write output to the file

```
var output = fs.createWriteStream('./stdout.log');
var errorOutput = fs.createWriteStream('./stderr.log');
var logger = new Console(output, errorOutput);
logger.log('log my stuff to the file');
```

but I cant see anything being written to the file. Why?
I can see just empty files 0 bytes.

I just found some mystery in my code.
When I am commenting that code bwlow then the logger is working, but when I am uncommenting that code the logger is not working:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
child = exec(cmd,
             function (error, stdout, stderr) { 

                 console.log(cmd);

                 if (error !== null) {
                      console.log(error);
                 }
             })
```

I do not have any issues/errors withe a code it is all working. But loggin is not working whem I am calling `child = exec...`

The documentation on [Console](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html) is saying:

> The global console is a special Console whose output is sent to
>   process.stdout and process.stderr

So in my case wne I am running `child = exec...` it is running another proess so may be it is breaking `Console.Log()` ... Any thoughts?

Comment: It works, it prints 'log my stuff to the file' in stdout.log

Answer (score 0):

The complete script should be this:

```
var Console = require('console').Console,
    fs = require('fs'),
    output = fs.createWriteStream('./stdout.log'),
    errorOutput = fs.createWriteStream('./stderr.log'),
    logger = new Console(output, errorOutput);

logger.log('log my stuff to the file');
```

Comment: What's the problem, you can do it, `function test () { logger.log('log my stuff to the file'); }`

Comment: Yes I just trying to understand why sometime it is just not wiriting anything but sometimes it is does

Comment: If you can post some code I could help otherwise no.

Comment: Ifter I debug a bit of my code I found out that wnen I commenting some part of it then `logger.log` is working. Otherwhise it is not. But I need that code to be executed. Just updated the question with the code I am talking about.